# VHDL how to code a Mealy NSTT

Tags: vhdl

Noob here, I remember back in school learning how to code a Mealy next state transition table and deriving this equation using k-maps and then coding the actually equations for all the outputs rather than coding states with a bunch of if-else statements.

I found [here](https://www.mil.ufl.edu/3701/classes/joel/16%20Lecture.pdf) how to setup the tables and kind of derive the equations but what's next? How do I implement these into the current_state and next_state's and program the output logic equations?

I've searched far and wide online and I can't find a thing on it. Is there a certain name for this? Maybe I'm Googling the wrong thing?

Any info, examples and guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: If the if-else statements are the clearest way to describe what you are trying to accomplish, I suggest just using them and letting the synthesis tool do its job.

Comment: As @Justin said, the whole point of using an HDL is that you don't need to derive logic equations. Just write behavioral HDL that does what you need it to do and let the CAD tools do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Is there a name for this? Yes, "1980's design methods". Designs today are typically done in HDL, with a synthesis optimizer to deal with reducing the equations to the minimum logic for you.

Comment: Don’t use if-else. Use switch. If-else is sequential.

Comment: @thephoton I wanted to do this method because all cases in all states are totally deterministic without having to type out all the redundant cases

Answer (score 0):

I will expand on the comments posted here by showing you how to code a VHDL state machine so that the tools compute these transition tables.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SimpleFSM is
  port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    input : in std_logic;
    output : out std_logic
  );
end entity SimpleFSM;

architecture fsm of SimpleFSM is
  -- This type represents all of your states by name
  type state_t is (
    STATE_BEGIN,
    STATE_END
  );
  -- And this is signal which holds the current state.
  signal state : state_t := STATE_BEGIN;
begin
  process (clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      case (state) is
        -- This is to say, if the current state is 'STATE_BEGIN'
        when STATE_BEGIN =>
          -- You can change the output based on the state.
          -- NOTE that this is one cycle delayed from when you entered the state.
          -- To change the output on the same cycle,
          -- use some combinational logic outside the process.
          output <= '0';
          -- This is your transition logic. Much easier to read, I think.
          -- Any logic suitable for a process (such as an if-elsif-else chain)
          -- can be used to make this choice,
          -- and the tools (simulator, synthesis) will calculate a transition function for you.
          if (input = '1') then
            state <= STATE_END;
          end if;
          -- By default, it stays in the same state
        when STATE_END =>
          output <= '1';
          if (input = '0') then
            state <= STATE_BEGIN;
          end if;
      end case;
    end if;
  end process;
end fsm;
```